# RouterFunction defined mappings in spring boot actuator

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

If I enable the Spring Boot Actuator Mappings endpoint, then I can browse to http://SERVER-XXXX/actuator/mappings
and see all of the request mappings. (For example: `"predicate":"{GET [/r4]}","details":{"handlerMethod":...}`.
However, this does not seem to include mappings defined using the `RouterFunction` method. For example, in the below code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public ServerResponse r1(ServerRequest ignored) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body("route1");
    }

    public ServerResponse r2(ServerRequest ignored) {
        return ServerResponse.ok().body("route2");
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> funcRoutes() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .GET("/r1", this::r1)
                .GET("/r2", this::r2)
                .build();
    }

    @RestController
    public static class Routes {

        @GetMapping("/r3")
        public String r3() {
            return "route3";
        }

        @GetMapping("/r4")
        public String r4() {
            return "route4";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication springApp = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        springApp.setDefaultProperties(Map.of(
                "management.endpoints.web.exposure.include", "mappings"
        ));
        springApp.run(args);
    }

}
```

Using the above code, if I browse to http://SERVER-XXXX/actuator/mappings then routes r3 and r4 are visible in the mappings, but r1 and r2 are not shown in the mappings.

Is there any way to configure the actuator to show those mappings? Or is there some explanation why these cannot be shown?